# Does SpriteKit support more than one camera?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am looking for a way to have two views into the same scene using sprite kit. I am putting the phone in landscape and dividing the screen in half. On the left half I see the part of the scene and on the right half I see the other part of the scene. I can do some trickery to make this work but I would prefer just have two cameras to streamline my game logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean "views", not "camera".

Technically it is possible, but it doesn't really work well enough to be of any use. Last time I tried was one of the late iOS 7 betas. I was able to create two SKView instances with some sprites and display them on the screen.

However only one view instance received regular updates, the other updated rarely or just once initially and never again. With SKView intended to run as fast as possible it's understandable that one will take every available resource while the other receives none, or only very occassionally.

So you'll have one 60 fps view and any other view is more or less static at under 1 fps.